# Symfony2: How to disable cache warm

Tags: symfony

How to completely disable cache warming for Symfony2 ?

I.e. the files that are being created in app/cache/

Comment: Have you seen this question+anwer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7192357/symfony2-disable-cache

Comment: Ah. Great! Ok, will summarize the solution: Just comment "$kernel->loadClassCache();" in "web/app.php"